# How do Configure the intellij plugin openapi.diagnostic.Logger CONSOLE logging level when developing a Plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, logging, intellij-plugin

When developing a simple plugin I have code like this:

```
import com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger;

public class MyClass {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getInstance(MyClass .class.getName());

     public MyClass(){
        LOG.warn("Creating class warn");
        LOG.info("Creating class info");
    }
 }
```

I see in this thread https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206779715-Proper-way-to-log-in-Idea-plugins
Using this API is the recommended way of logging...

However, in the Console output, whe I run the plugin in the sandbox IDE, I only see the WARN level output. (I am using GrepConsole, but i checked and am not squelching any INFO levels).

I also manually checked the file in sandbox/system/logs/idea.log and the INFO statements are there.... they are just not getting to my IDE console.

Is there a way I can configure my project to allow INFO level output using this logging class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> also manually checked the file in sandbox/system/logs/idea.log and the INFO statements are there.... they are just not getting to my IDE console.

This is expected. The console prints the **standard error/output** stream. And the logger writes logs into the idea.log file.

Comment: is there a way to redirect the log to the console? Its annoying having to switch between the two tabs 30 times every few minutes etc..

Comment: You can redirect console output to a file, using the **Redirect input** option  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#createExplicitly But no option to di a vice versa.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question "How to configure...". I am assuming there is in fact a way to configure what log-levels are visible (I mean that seems to be the whole point of using a logging framework).